# how to force images to show in portrait?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a web page that contain images in bootstrap card but some of them in landscape and some in portrait so how I force all images to show in portrait preferably using only css or bootstrap 4 or html5.

here is my code:

```
<div class="card mb-4"style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;"> 
<img src="images/1.jpeg" alt="image" class="card-img-top img-responsive">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to require some form of cropping using a div element. It is hard to tell exactly what you are after without seeing the website, but here is one potential solution using `height:0;` and a percentage `padding-bottom` to create a div with a fixed aspect ratio and then using a background image instead of an image.

If you wanted to still use an image you would either need to use Javascript or the new `object-fit` CSS property, but `object-fit` isn't supported by IE.

```css
.portrait {
  height:0;
  padding-bottom:150%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card mb-4"style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
  <div class="portrait" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/200x300);"></div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card mb-4"style="min-width: 18rem; max-width: 18rem;">
  <div class="portrait" style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x200);"></div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```